# Can we share a site with public users using a link

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, anonymous-authentication, anonymous-access

In SharePoint online we can share a file or folder using anonymous links, so users without login can view the file or folder, but can we do the same for a whole site or a whole library? so the site or library can be accessed using a public/anonymous link?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that we cannot share a site with public users using a link.
[image]

[SharePoint Online Public Websites to be discontinued](https://Here%20is%20the%20reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sites/public-websites-be-discontinued)